# special characters (not given in keyboard) need to use in Java

Tags: java

Want use special charecters ex : `(£, ¥)` which not there in keyboard to prepare some String.

Comment: Try alt+[arbitrary key] and see what the result is. You see, there are more characters on the keyboard then you can see

Comment: For example: alt+1: ¡, alt+2, €, +3: £, +4: ¢, +y: ¥

Comment: When I have to, I google them by name and copy+paste into the code.

Comment: alt+shift+[arbitrary key] works also!

Comment: It's really unclear what exactly you mean. By the way, how did you type the £ and ¥ in your question if they are not on your keyboard?

Comment: @Jesper i copied from some site

Comment: So, what is your question about? How you type those characters? Does it really have anything to do with programming in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the unicode character code for the character you can use the \uXXXX method for putting characters into a string in the code.

Comment: I would advise against doing that, because it's very hard to read.

Comment: @Philipp It is still better than using a character not commonly supported in the editor fonts, if such characters are indeed used.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, there is a nice utility called charmap.exe which lists all available character in each font. You can easily copy&paste characters from there.

When you need more obscure unicode characters, you can try to find them on one of these websites and copy&paste them:

http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/index.php

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode

http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a table of alt+numpad keys you can type to get symbols on Windows

http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html

In your case ALT+156 is £ and ALT+157 or 190 is ¥ depending on your keyboard setting

Comment: That's on the numpad and for windows. On a mac it is £ = alt+3, alt+y = ¥

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using UNICODE in your Java Code like this example:

```
    //Use a string literal to assign a value to the String
    String address = "I live at 22b Baker Street!";

    //The same string but using Unicode values
    String unicodeAddress = "\u0049\u0020\u006C\u0069\u0076\u0065"
            + "\u0020\u0061\u0074\u0020\u0032\u0032\u0042\u0020"
            + "\u0042\u0061\u006B\u0065\u0072\u0020\u0053\u0074"
            + "\u0072\u0065\u0065\u0074\u0021";

    System.out.println("Here is Sherlock's address: " + address); 
    System.out.println("It even works using Unicode characters: " + unicodeAddress);
```

Example taken from [here](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/ss/Fun-With-Strings-Example-Code.htm).

Also I find [this resource](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) useful to lookup the unicodes.

It avoids all kinds of problems associated with Encoding of special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in which the special character is present using Notepad++ (on Windows) or any text editor. Then, copy that character and paste it in this URL (https://unicode-table.com/en/). By this way, you can get the four digit unicode of that character.

For example, in this pseudo code checks if the special character (Right Arrow) is present in the string or not.

```
String s = "[O2] = 8.1 ppb→ 0 ppb";

if(s.indexOf("\u2192") != -1)
{
    System.out.println("Character \u2192 is present in the string");
}
```